# ¿Cómo añadir datos a un <input type="text">

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo una duda muy básica que creía saber pero que me está volviendo loco. Ayuda, please!!!

Os cuento, es sencillo...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script>
  document.f1.f1t1.value = 30
  </script>
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form name="f1" id="f1">
  <input type="text" name="f1t1" id="f1t1">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Yo quiero imprimir el número 30 dentro del campo de texto desde JavaScript, como valor por defecto y de inicio. Entiendo que esta es la sintaxis correcta pues accedo al campo de formulario siguiendo su jerarquía DOM y le indico que su valor es 30.

Pues bien, lo que me ocurre es que en pantalla mi campo de texto me carga vacío y el inspector de Google Chrome me dice que "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'f1t1' of undefined". Es como si no reconociera el objeto "f1" y además como si interpretase "f1t1" como una propiedad de "f1".

Bueno, ahí dejo la duda a ver si alguien me echa un cable.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Entiendo lo que quieres hacer, aunque hay otras formas más elaboradas de hacerlo.

Para que te funcione tal y como querés hacerlo, tienes que colocar el script en el **body**, despues de tu etiqueta **form**.

De la siguiente forma:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>

</head>
<body>
  <form name="f1" id="f1">
    <input type="text" name="f1t1" id="f1t1">
  </form>

  <script>
    document.f1.f1t1.value = 30
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

De ésta forma, tu script se ejecutará cuando los controles (formulario y textbox) ya estén cargados en el DOM.

Si querés ver el código funcionando te lo dejo en JSBIN: http://jsbin.com/zafaset/edit?html,console,output

Comment: Muchas gracias. Ese era el error, estoy cargando el JavaScript en el <head> y todavía no se ha creado el objeto de formulario. Por eso no lo encuentra.

Muchas gracias otra vez.

Answer (score 8):

Si utiliza jquery, puede hacer asi:

HTML

```
<input type="text" name="f1t1" id="f1t1">
```

JAVASCRIPT/jQuery

```
$("#f1t1").val('30');
```

"$" refiere a jQuery; entonces puede buscar el elemento con "("#f1t1")" y despues asignar el valor con ".val('30');"

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta pero no conozco aún jQuery. Todo llegará...

Comment: Vale la pena si te echo a vista a eso: jquery es mas poderoso y tambien menos dificil que javascript solo.

Comment: Lo tendré en cuenta, sin duda. Es una de las metas que tengo para el futuro próximo. El problema es que tengo muchas metas pendientes... (Bootstrap, PHP, Less, Sass, PostCSS...)

Comment: ahi te dejo un punto

Answer (score 3):

Te falta decirle a Js en que momento queres que se imprima.

Cuando Carga el DOM, se Crea la función  "X" y se le indica a js que al inicio ejecute esa función con window.onload = X;

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script>
function inicio(){
       document.f1.f1t1.value = 30
    };
    window.onload = inicio;
 
  </script>
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form name="f1" id="f1">
  <input type="text" name="f1t1" id="f1t1">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta. La verdad es que quería hacerlo sin una función y la respuesta de Wanderson Peraza ha sido justo lo que buscaba.